# How to have oracle imp 11gr2 and 12cr2 on the same machine and just choose the one that I want to use

Tags: oracle, import, redhat, impdp, imp

I'm currently developing an application to import oracle dbs. In order to do that I'm using `Data Pump` and the original imp client (version `12.2.0.1`). However I cannot use that imp client against an `11gr2` database, I need to use the `11gr2` imp client.

I already have the client and libraries that I got from one of my `11gr2` DBs however, if I try to execute it I'm getting the following error:

> Message 100 not found; No message file for product=RDBMS,
>   facility=IMP: Release 11.2.0.3.0 - Production on Fri Jan 5 18:28:21
>   2018
>
> Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracl
>
> Invalid format of Import utility name
>
> Verify that ORACLE_HOME is properly set
>
> Import terminated unsuccessfully
>
> IMP-00000: Message 0 not found; No message file for product=RDBMS,
>   facility=IMP

Can someone point how to have both clients working on the same machine? Thanks in advance.

[UPDATE]
I'm using Red Hat OS and this is the output of $ORACLE_HOME:
/root/oracle/instantclient_12_2

I tried using the full path and placing the files in ORACLE_HOME but I still get the same error. Thanks!!!

Comment: what's your OS (unix or windows based)? What do you get whan you issue `echo %ORACLE_HOME%`( If windows based ), or `echo $ORACLE_HOME`(If unix based)?

Comment: Please see my update, is Red Hat and I included the ORACLE_HOME path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching, I did not copy all the required files when trying to copy the imp client version 11cr2. I solved this issue by copying all the files in $ORACLE_HOME and making that location my new $ORACLE_HOME. After that, just copied the lib files and the imp from the 12cr2 client installation to $ORACLE_HOME and renamend imp 12cr2 to "imp12cr2".

Now if I want to use the 11.2 I use **imp** and if want to use the 12cr2 one I use **imp12cr2**

Answer (score 1):

On a Windows machine, I usually changed directory (using the `CD` command) to the one that contains IMP I wanted to use, for example:

```
C:\>
C:\>cd C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin

C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin>imp help=y

Import: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Sub Sij 6 06:45:43 2018
```

Or, alternatively, if you call those utilities by specifying full path to their executables, such as

```
C:\>
C:\>C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin\imp help=y

Import: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Sub Sij 6 06:47:30 2018
```

I hope you'd be able to do what you're up to.

Comment: Thanks but I'm using Red Hat and I've tried with the full path but it does not work either.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably your problem is related to setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `PATH` to the Instant Client directory. You may perform all settings in your bash shell script like .`bash_profile`, `.profile`, `.bashrc` :

1. First of all set

   ```
   ORACLE_HOME=/root/oracle/instantclient_12_2; export ORACLE_HOME
   ```
2. Add the name of the directory containing the Instant Client libraries to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Remove any other Oracle directories.
   For example, to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in the Bourne or Korn shells, use the following syntax:

   ```
   LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${ORACLE_HOME}/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
   ```

   Or, to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in the `C` shell, use the following syntax:

   ```
   % setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH 
   $ORACLE_HOME/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
   ```
3. Make sure the Tools executables installed from the `RPM` are the first executables found in your `PATH`. For example, to test this you could enter `which impdp` which should return `$ORACLE_HOME/bin/impdp`. If it does not, then remove any other Oracle directories from `PATH`, or put `$ORACLE_HOME/bin` before other Tools executables in `PATH`, or use an absolute or relative path to start Tools Instant Client.
   For example, to set `PATH` in the bash shell:

   ```
   PATH=/usr/bin:${PATH}:${ORACLE_HOME}:${ORACLE_HOME}/bin
   export PATH
   ```
4. Set Oracle globalization variables required for your locale. A default locale will be assumed if no variables are set.

   ```
   NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8
   export NLS_LANG
   ```